# How can I force an ethernet device to disable autonegotiation on boot

Tags: linux, networking, android-source, drivers

I have a device and am trying to force link speed to 100mbps without autonegotiation. I'm running an Android system, with a 3.4.48 kernel and the smsc911x driver.

If I compile ethtool, I can force the connection state manually. However, the phy driver seems to continue in the autonegotiate state machine and I see "Trying 100/Half" if it doesn't work.

I see that there are ways to do this during initialization, but I have a feeling that it isn't the "correct" solution.  Here's an example:

https://ez.analog.com/thread/49703

I feel like there should be a configuration that wouldn't involve modification to the driver directly, either from deep in the AOSP source (Jellybean) or during an initialization script in Android.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://superuser.com. Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.